# How to change the color of a UIBezierPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have an instance of `UIBezierPath` and I want to change the color of the stroke to something other than black. Does anyone know how to do this in Swift?

Comment: POB's answer is helpful here, but it's important to understand that a Bézier path itself has no color. It is a description of a curve. Only pens have color, and POB's answer is all about setting the pen color.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With Swift 5, `UIColor` has a [`setStroke()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621948-setstroke) method. `setStroke()` has the following declaration:

```
func setStroke()
```

> Sets the color of subsequent stroke operations to the color that the receiver represents.

Therefore, you can use `setStroke()` like this:

```
strokeColor.setStroke() // where strokeColor is a `UIColor` instance
```

---

The Playground code below shows how to use `setStroke()` alongside `UIBezierPath` in order to draw a circle with a green fill color and a light grey stroke color inside a `UIView` subclass:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // UIBezierPath
        let newRect = CGRect(
            x: bounds.minX + ((bounds.width - 79) * 0.5 + 0.5).rounded(.down),
            y: bounds.minY + ((bounds.height - 79) * 0.5 + 0.5).rounded(.down),
            width: 79,
            height: 79
        )
        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newRect)

        // Fill
        UIColor.green.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()

        // Stroke
        UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
        ovalPath.lineWidth = 5
        ovalPath.stroke()
    }

}

let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myView
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you want to use the color red instead to stroke a rounded rectangle;
This is how you do it in Swift 3 :

```
    // Drawing the border of the rounded rectangle:
    let redColor = UIColor.red
    redColor.setStroke() // Stroke subsequent views with a red color
    let roundedRectagle = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 90,height: 20)
    let rectangleBorderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRectangle,cornerRadius: 5)
    roundedRectangle.borderWidth = 1
    roundedRectangle.stroke() // Apply the red color stroke on this view
```

The second and last lines of the above code are important in answering your question.I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: Do you think roundedRectangle of type CGRect has borderWidth property?? :)))