# How can I change the color of an element using a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibezierpath

First post on stackoverflow so, first and foremost, hello!

I'm trying my hand at Swift for the first time and am working a project and just needed some help on a problem I'm having. I've got a circle using a UIBezierPath that I'd like to change the color of, dynamically. However, when I try to even "hard code" the color, I'm unable to get it to change. I've tried looking here: [How to change the color of a UIBezierPath in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533091/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibezierpath-in-swift), but it didn't answer my question. However, I do see that one answer there does state that a Bezier path has no color. If so, how would I then go about altering the color of the circle going along its path?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
    outerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)).CGPath
    outerCircle.lineWidth = 8.0
    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.45
    outerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    outerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    outerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    outerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(outerCircle)

    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0

    vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(outerCircleView)

    innerCircleView.frame.size = frameSize

    let innerCirclePadding: CGFloat = 12
    innerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: innerCirclePadding, y: innerCirclePadding, width: frameSize.width - 2*innerCirclePadding, height: frameSize.height - 2*innerCirclePadding)).CGPath
    innerCircle.lineWidth = 4.0
    innerCircle.strokeStart = 0.5
    innerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.9
    innerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    innerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    innerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    innerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(innerCircle)
```

Again, I apologize if this is an obvious answer or has already been answered. I appreciate any advice that would help point me in the right direction. Thank you.

UPDATE:  So here's what I tried doing. I changed the fill and stroke colors of both inner and outer circles to green, but I still have clear circles:

```
        outerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)).CGPath
    outerCircle.lineWidth = 8.0
    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.45
    outerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    outerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    outerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    outerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(outerCircle)

    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0

    vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(outerCircleView)

    innerCircleView.frame.size = frameSize

    let innerCirclePadding: CGFloat = 12
    innerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: innerCirclePadding, y: innerCirclePadding, width: frameSize.width - 2*innerCirclePadding, height: frameSize.height - 2*innerCirclePadding)).CGPath
    innerCircle.lineWidth = 4.0
    innerCircle.strokeStart = 0.5
    innerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.9
    innerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    innerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    innerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    innerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(innerCircle)
```

I'd like to have the circles change colors.

Comment: And those would be operations on the outer and inner circles. Got it. Thank you! Exactly the guidance I was looking for. I was trying to alter the fillColor and strokeColor, but I need to use these two functions instead. Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, what do fillColor and strokeColor, then, do in the code above, if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: What _are_ `innerCircle` and `outerCircle`? Are they, by any chance, shape layers? If so, don't you think it might be kind of a good idea to mention that fact in your question?

Comment: Okay, so what you're doing is correct as far as it goes. What's the question, then? Show more of your code. Show enough that someone else can _run_ your code. And _explain_ what the problem is - what is happening when you run the code, and what, on the other hand, do you _want_ to have happen?

Comment: What I want to do is edit the colors of innerCircle and outerCircle. Trying to do that manually altering the fillColor and strokeColor elements didn't work for me. I have to use setStroke and setFill instead?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work for me"? I can see that you _are_ setting their `fillColor` and `strokeColor` properties. That is correct and it works. What, I ask again, is the problem?

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly. I still don't see what the question is.

Comment: I tried changing fillColor to UIColor.greenColor().CGColor and the circles were still gray. Is there something else I should be setting to have the colors appear?

Comment: Show me the code where you "tried changing `fillColor`". Show your code! Don't talk about it. Don't talk around it. Show it. Your code, as shown so far, _works perfectly_. I still don't see what the question is.

Comment: Added what I'm trying to do to the original post

Comment: I tried your second code and got a green circle, just as I would expect. My answer shows the code I'm running and what I get when I run it. I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps something else in the code is affecting the color? I'm getting a clear circle ( can't post screenshots yet). I'll post the rest of my code.

Comment: I think you should stop and do some thinking and testing. I believe this question is answered and exhausted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A path has no color. It's a path! Only a graphics context has a stroke color / fill color. Sooner or later you will have a graphics context - a bezier path is useless without one. When you do, set its path to your bezier path, set its stroke / fill color as desired, and then stroke / fill the path. Voilà.

In your case, you seem to have a pair of CAShapeLayer objects. You can change *their* stroke / fill colors, because they have a graphics context - they take the path and colors you give them, and draw them for you by filling and stroking the path. Fine. But you cannot change a bezier path's stroke or fill color - it's just a path. The entire notion is meaningless.

Having said all that, it is far from clear what issue you are having. Based on your code, I ran this bit of it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outerCircleView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let outerCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        let frameSize = outerCircleView.frame.size
        outerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)).CGPath
        outerCircle.lineWidth = 8.0
        outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
        outerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.45
        outerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        outerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        outerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        outerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(outerCircle)

    }
}
```

It builds and runs, and I see *exactly* what I would expect to see: a thick gray part-circle:

[image]

That is because this shape layer has a clear fill color and a grey stroke color. If you don't like those colors, ask the shape layer to give you different colors.

**UPDATE** You updated your code to show a second version involving green fill and stroke. So I tried your second code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let outerCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = outerCircleView.frame.size
    outerCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)).CGPath
    outerCircle.lineWidth = 8.0
    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 0.45
    outerCircle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    outerCircle.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    outerCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    outerCircleView.layer.addSublayer(outerCircle)

    outerCircle.strokeStart = 0.0
    outerCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0

}
```

And, as expected, I got a green circle (it isn't an exact circle, but that is just because my view is not a perfect square):

[image]

So again I don't see what the problem is supposed to be: your code does just what I would expect your code to do.